# How to reduce Amazon Cloudfront costs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, wordpress

I have a site that has exploded in traffic the last few days. I'm using Wordpress with W3 Total Cache plugin and Amazon Cloudfront to deliver the images and files from the site.

The problem is that the cost of Cloudfront is quite huge, near $500 just the past week. Is there a way to reduce the costs? Maybe using another CDN service?

I'm new to CDN, so I might not be implementing this well. I've created a cloudfront distribution and configured it on W3 Total Cache Plugin. However, I'm not using S3 and don't know if I should or how. To be honest, I'm not quite sure what's the difference between Cloudfront and S3.

Can anyone give me some hints here?

Comment: Well first off...Congratulations are in order. You are doing what all of us want to do with our site.  Hopefully someone will have a constructive answer for you.

Comment: There are ways for reducing cost for CloudFront, can you please elaborate on the kind of numbers you are looking at ? Do you analyse your CloudFront logs to find out geographical distribution and validity of the traffic ? This might provide you useful insight which will help you in optimizing your infrastructure cost.

Answer (score 16):

> I'm not quite sure what's the difference between Cloudfront and S3.

That's easy. S3 is a data store. It stores files, and is super-scalable (easily scaling to serving 1000's of people at once.)  The problem is that it's centralized (i.e. served from one place in the world.)

CloudFront is a CDN. It caches your files all over the world so they can be served faster. If you squint, it looks like they are 'storing' your files, but the cache can be lost at any time (or if they boot up a new node), so you still need the files at your origin.

CF may actually hurt you if you have too few hits per file. For example, in Tokyo, CF may have 20 nodes. It may take 100 requests to a file before all 20 CF nodes have cached your file (requests are randomly distributed). Of those 100 requets, 20 of them will hit an empty cache and see an additional 200ms latency as it fetches the file. They generally cache your file for a long time.

> I'm not using S3 and don't know if I should

Probably not. Consider using S3 if you expect your site to massively grow in media. (i.e. lots of use photo uploads.)

> Is there a way to reduce the costs? Maybe using another CDN service?

That entirely depends on your site. Some ideas:

1) Make sure you are serving the [appropriate headers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Expiration.html). And make sure your expires time isn't too short (should be days or weeks, or months, ideally).

The "best practice" is to never expire pages, except maybe your index page which should expire every X minutes or hours or days (depending on how fast you want it updated.)  Make sure every page/image says how long it can be cached.

2) As stated above, CF is only useful if each page is requested > 100's of times per cache time. If you have millions of pages, each requested a few times, CF may not be useful.

3) Requests from Asia are much more expensive than the from the US. Consider launching your server in Toyko if you're more popular there.

4) Look at your web server log and see how often CF is requesting each of your assets. If it's more often than you expect, your cache headers are setup wrong.  If you setup "cache this for months", you should only see a handful of requests per day (as they boot new servers, etc), and a few hundred requests when you publish a new file (i.e. one request per CF edge node).

Depending on your setup, other CDNs may be cheaper. And depending on your server, other setups may be less expensive. (i.e. if you serve lots of small files, you might be better off doing your own caching on EC2.)

Answer (score 3):

You could give cloudflare a go. It's not a full CDN so it might not have all the features as cloudfront, but the basic package is free and it will offload a lot of traffic from your server.

https://www.cloudflare.com

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Cloudfront costs Based on 2 factor

1. Number of Requests
2. Data Transferred in GB

**Solution**

1. Reduce image requests. For that combine small images into one image and use that image 
   https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sprites_img (image sprites)
2. Don't use CDN for video file because video size is high and this is responsible for too high in CDN coast

Comment: and what would you use for large videos? What's the solution?

Comment: @GabryelFerreira Check out peer-assisted video streaming https://peervadoo.com/. I have seen savings up-to 90% in my experiments.

Answer (score 0):

What components make up your bill? One thing to check with W3 Total Cache plugin is the number of invalidation requests it is sending to CloudFront. It's known to send a large amount of invalidations paths on each change, which can add up.

Aside from that, if your spend is predictable, one option is to use **CloudFront Security Savings Bundle** to save up to 30% by committing to a minimum amount for a one year period. It's self-service, so you can sign up in the console and purchase additional commitments as your usage grows.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/savings-bundle.html

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that cloudfront has 3 different price classes, which will influence how far your data is being replicated, but at the same time, it will make it cheaper.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PriceClass.html

The key here is this:
"If you choose a price class that doesn’t include all edge locations, CloudFront might still occasionally serve requests from an edge location in a region that is not included in your price class. When this happens, you are not charged the rate for the more expensive region. Instead, you’re charged the rate for the least expensive region in your price class."

It means that you could use price class 100 (the cheapest one) and still get replication on regions you are not paying for <3