# How to optimize cloudfront distribution to reduce costs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I was following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22752280/how-to-reduce-amazon-cloudfront-costs) to optimize Cloudfront costs but
my architecture is a little bit different

I have a Cloudfront distribution in front of a lambda function (api gateway) that makes en http call to a image hosted in another server then resizes it to a given size and returns it. then Cloudfront caches it for 1 year. I´m not storing the resized images in S3 at all. I set the expiration to 1 year.

what are some good options to reduce Cloudfront costs? is the 1 year expiration a good practice?

**Amazon CloudFront SA-Requests-Tier2-HTTPS**
5,561,818.000 Requests: $12.24

**bandwith: $0.110 per GB - first 10 TB / month data transfer out**
355.339 GB: $39.09

Comment: If you only use CF for api gateway, you may consider eliminating self-managed CF distro, and switch your API to edge optimized. Have you looked into that?

Comment: looks like is a 2mb limitation of the file for edge optimized. also.. hows that going to help reducing the cloudfront cost? so far lambda cost are not alarming :)

Answer (score 2):

Amazon CloudFront will *not* cache your object for one year.

CloudFront points of presence have large, but not infinite, storage. When the cache space fills up, less-frequently accessed files are removed. If your image is infrequently accessed, then it will *not* be stored in CloudFront for a long period.

Instead, CloudFront will call the back-end again, so your API Gateway will receive a request for a resized object again.